# How to debug Chrome SSL issue

Tags: ssl, google-chrome

I have a site secured with SSL. It's a single page application. The application communicates with a back-end REST service using mostly POST operations.

The application loads perfectly fine but calling the back-end REST service fails. Using the security tab in Chrome's developer tools shows that the SSL cert is perfectly valid.

If I try to run the application in IE it works perfectly fine (i.e. the REST API calls work fine) but it just doesn't work in Chrome. If I switch off Require SSL the application works perfectly fine (but obviously not securely).

If I try to perform a GET on the back-end service by typing the URL directly into the browser this works fine in Chrome, so it's just POST operations that aren't working.

I'm scratching my head as to how to debug this. Is there another, lower-level tool I can use to discover what is going on?

There is no actual error code showing for the requests in the network tab in Chrome - just 0() on the console. This would seem to indicate that the back-end just isn't returning anything.

Comment: What call are you trying to make? What failure do you see? Please be specific. This description is much too vague. See also [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was happening because my code was setting an empty Authorization header which Chrome was refusing to send to the server.

See here: [Similar problem on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468033/err-spdy-protocol-error-ajax-net-web-api/51775687#51775687)